# Bytes32 half value dropped in Solidity

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

When I was trying to store the long hash string into Solidity with Bytes32 data type, I noticed that the outcome value was half dropped.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Here is my code:

```js
// Struct Data
struct Data {
    bytes32 hashFile;

}

// Persits bytes32 into Solidity
function addData(bytes32 _hashFile) {
    require(_hashFile > 0);

    ContractData memory contractData;
    contractData.hashFile = _hashFile;
    contractData.contractState = ContractState.Created;

    contracts[Id] = contractData;
}

// Retrieve the bytes32 value
function getDocumentHash() constant external returns (bytes32) {
    return contracts[_contractId].hashFile;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code along with input and expected results. Hard to help without it.

Comment: @AdamKipnis - Sorry the missed earlier. I have added the source code here.

Comment: I don't see the client input, but since you said "long hash string", I'm going to guess your input is longer than 32 bytes causing your data to be truncated. Take a look at this question on when to use strings vs bytes32: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11556/use-string-type-or-bytes32

Comment: @AdamKipnis - This is the input hash string - 4a5a45db1d68ec66145ee39b245da34765999dbad1d5bd7094ec87f6dc264561

Comment: @AdamKipnis - Thank you for the sharing above(the link). I've studied this before, the reason why I choose Bytes32 it was because of reduced gas consumption. In this case, unlikely I can use the Bytes32 to store the extended hash string value?

Comment: Yeah, that won't fit into a 32 byte array. You can either use a string (as long as this isn't being called by another contract), send your hash in parts (ie, use `bytes32 part1` `bytes32 part2`), or use a different hashing algorithm.

Comment: @AdamKipnis - Thank you so much. I just thought the same as you did, I am going to do the first option, which to cut the long string into chunks. You mentioned another hashing algorithm, what would you recommend other than sha256?

Comment: If you're using sha256, that is 32 bytes. The issue you're having is your converting the results from 32 bytes (in hex) to a 64 byte string representing the hex characters. Just use the raw byte representation when hashing and pass that in.

Comment: @AdamKipnis - I got it. Many Thanks!

Comment: In the end, I made a comparison between using a bytes32 and a string the gas consumption is not much different. Well, my second thought is perhaps, storing a string is not a bad idea in this case, and rather than perform a significant function in the Solidity code just to iterate the bytes array. What do you think? @AdamKipnis